# Change attributes order in Drupal Commerce

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce

So I have a shop on Drupal commerce with a few products. I have a size option with a price variation (XL, L, M, S), this is a taxonomy vocabulary. Everything was okay with the bulk add products.

But then we've decided that we want to show the smallest product first instead of the biggest. So I've changed the taxonomy order but I guess as the product SKU was created from the largest to the smallest, by default the XL is still selected.

Is there a way to change this order or do I need to manually overide the SKU (1 would be the smallest then) ?

Thanks